# Set default value in cell dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using In-Cell-Dropdown in Excel cell, I want Default value "Select" should be shown in the dropdown cell always,If there is no value is selected. please let us know, how to achieve that.

In validation source I have tried that using offset formula, but expected result didn't come. this is the formula I tried.

```
=IF($F$4=44,OFFSET($Y$4,0,0,Counta($Y$4:$Y$6) -1,1),OFFSET($S$4,0,0,Counta($S$4:$S$8)-1,1))
```

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3599-excel-drop-down-list-preselected-value.html#a1

Comment: It will be much easier if you can show some data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this macro free method,

Step 1 : Insert a rectangular shape and refer the shape text from some other cell by selecting the rectangle textbox frame then in the formula bar type `=J1`.

- Now "assigned", the J1 Value appears in the floating textbox.
- Bonus: J1 font formatting (i.e., color, font type...)  is also
  captured upon [each time] assigning `=J1` to the text box.

[image]

Step 2 : Write a formula in the cell that you've referred in the shape

[image]

Step 3 : Reposition that rectangle textbox so it overlays on top of the data validation cell, here at H1.

- Keep a bit of room to make appear the actual picker dropdown arrow
  when *cell* selecting.
- Lock the shape so it doesn't get deleted and then when you select
  value default selection will disappear and when you delete selection
  it will appear again.

[image]

For other readers on a similar quest *show the first item in list as default text when cell is blank*, replace "-- Select Value--" with "F1" here so formula becomes `=IF(H1="",F1,H1)`.

P.S : If you don't need to retain value after the initial selection you can write a formula like this.

[image]

P.P.S :

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry  Its not happening ,better if when the drop down is changing the range in side the source based on condition , i just want to clear the cell value , is that possible using formula ?

Comment: In that case you will not be able to retain the "select value" text , as soon as you select one value it will disappear.

Comment: In which cell i need to apply the =If(H4="","SelectValue") , in dropdown cell , that give error , not allowing to add formula

Comment: Please tell me how to set first value of list to show in drop down , whenever it populate in excel cell

Comment: @baskar Go to error alert and unchecked the option there.